# loading jquery from code and use document.ready in the page

Tags: jquery

im trying to load the jquery from the code to prevent double loading of the jquery js file. Just curious how can I do that and still be able to use document.ready to perform operation after document is loaded complete.

thanks

Comment: when you say loading it from code, can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with code-fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Just load jQuery with a `<script>` tag. Really.

Comment: @SLaks: so you put in the the `<head>`. Where's the problem?

Comment: He's adding the `<script>` tag in code.  Therefore, it will load asynchronously, and his code will run before jQuery exists.

Comment: @SLaks: my point was, don't load jQuery with JavaScript. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) framework, which does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  !window.jQuery && (function() {
    alert("jQuery hasn't loaded");
  })();
</script>
```

Basically, write everything you want to do if jQuery hasn't loaded inside the anonymous function.